# How do I prove it for a general case?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

**Original question**: Let **A** and **B** be two points lying on opposite sides of a given line *l*. Find all point(s) **X** on *l* such that |**A**X − **B**X| is maximized

**My approach**: I started by taking a general line *l* : $y=mx+c$, assumed points **A** and **B** to be (*a*,*b*) and (*c*,*d*) respectively and on either side of the l. To prove that the point **X** lies on the foot of perpendicular of **A** and **B** (I assumed this to be true), I tried to use contradiction and ended up with too many unknowns. Is there a better method to solve this or please tell me if my assumption was wrong.

Comment: I assume that $l$ will be a tangent to the hyperbola with focii $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to be true. Let us define the hyperbola defined as

$$|d(A,X) -d(B,X)| = c$$

Here we need to find a maximum $c$ given a line $l$ for $X$. My hypothesis is that $l$ would need to be tangent to the curve. Using this, we can find $c$